# Unwrap can as stripes

Tags: uv

anybody could explain me why the top part of this can doesn't unwrap as a stripe?
unlike the middle and bottom sections?

here is the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TovTwIWuC7ZFFVMXBSQjhBX0k/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: You're probably missing a seam on the top, it looks like you have 2 loop overlapping right on the top of the cylinder edge.

Comment: @Denis maybe you can write the answer for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your image it looks like you have overlapping loops at the top of your cylinder, you can see that because of the face indicators appearing in the middle of the edges, and thats why you could not select the hidden edge to mark the seam and have a proper unwrap.